# Vagrant - Homestead Setup Multiple sites

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I have mapped the folders etc using the homestead.yaml;

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"

...

folders:
    - map: /Users/User/Desktop/folder/Homestead/First
      to: /home/vagrant/First

    - map: /Users/User/Desktop/folder/Homestead/Second
      to: /home/vagrant/Second

sites:
    - map: first.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/First/public

    - map: second.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Second/public
```

But when i set up the hosts file, `etc/hosts` with my second.dev to 192.168.10.10 i find that the mapping goes to first.dev, not the mapping that i have set up for second.dev.

How can i go about making the mapping return the correct site?

EDIT: I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Same here. Homestead is installed on a Windows machine and the hosts configuration is working properly. When I try to connect from a Mac to my Windows homestead via lan, it always load "first.dev"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using Vagrant commands**

Run the command `vagrant provision` within terminal or your command prompt within the folder where homestead files are located.

Another equivalent command is `vagrant up --provision` this will provision the vagrant machine as well as run it.

**Using Global Homestead**

You can use the command `homestead provision` to re-provision the vagrant machine, regardless of the place you call it from within the terminal.

Alternatively, you can use the `serve` command to add the information to your `Homestead.yaml` file for you. Like so;

```
serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public/directory
```

But add this to your hosts file so you can access the your app via domain.app in your browser.

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem. But where do you run the command vagrant provision ?

Comment: Within terminal/command prompt within the folder where your homestead is. Running vagrant up --provision will also work.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it only recognizes one site, even if a have two defined