# Laravel homestead IP address not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I’m using Laravel Homestead 2.0 for my VM and am trying to serve my sites on the default IP address in the YAML file 192.168.10.10

My /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```html
# Homestead
192.168.10.10   beta.dev
192.168.10.10   deploy.dev
```

My Homestead.yaml file looks like this:

```html
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: beta.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/emorybeta/public
    - map: deploy.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/deploy/public

...
```

The sites come up when I link my domains to 127.0.0.1 but I have to append port 8000 onto the end of the URL (which isn’t a big deal, I just want to get the specified IP address to work).

Does anyone know why I cannot connect to server when my domains are pointed to 192.168.10.10?

---

**UPDATE:**

When I ping deploy.dev the right IP address shows up, but still my browser can’t connect to the server. I’m thinking it might have something to do with DNS issues in Yosemite.

Comment: Innocent question, Did you run the command vagrant provision?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vagrant - Homestead Setup Multiple sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672310/vagrant-homestead-setup-multiple-sites)

Comment: For anyone who are still struggling on this, you need to match your php version to a proper homestead box version see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#old-versions). Been struggling on this for a week and did what it says and got it working.

Comment: In my experience, IP addresses can sometimes act "stale" on some devices, and I've benefited from changing my configs to use fresh IPs: https://superuser.com/a/1214376/74576

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problems a few weeks ago.

First:
make sure your folder paths are correct, if so, double check it

Next:
run homestead destroy and homestead up to reinitialize the VM

if that all didnt work:
Check if you have any devices at home that might also be on 192.168.10.10.

If that all didnt work, your problem is probably alot harder to fix and i'd suggest making a github issue for it.

Comment: I would suggest `vagrant reload --provision` instead of destroying and relaunching.

Comment: @GoogleMac did the trick for me - without having to destroy the image. I'm guessing my box had gone stale due to not being used for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I had this exact same problem. I eventually got it working by installing the deprecated net-tools package: 
`sudo apt-get update` and
`sudo apt-get install gnome-nettool`

After this,
`homestead destroy` and
`homestead up`

This allowed me to access my virtual machine sites from my local machine's browser using the 'domains' I specified in the hosts file - in your case beta.dev and deploy.dev - *without* referring to localhost or port 8000. Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: This also resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I did for my Windows 10 machine:

Make sure you add a persistent route to your vagrant box
In Administrator command prompt enter
**route -p add 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1**

And make sure you are able to **ping 192.168.10.10**

Also check the IP address configured for the virtualbox host-only adapter is 192.168.10.1 with mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: After hours of searching, this is what solved my problem.  Had to change the virtual box host-only adapter to 192.168.10.1  (it was using 192.168.10.10)  THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue yesterday for Homestead 5. It turned out the cause of my problem was that I was running the wrong Vagrantfile.

An instance should give a response to the ip address: 192.168.10.10

To correct the problem in my case what I did was to follow these instructions: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead

To recap:

In terminal run:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

then

```
cd ./Homestead
```

and run this command FROM INSIDE the new "Homestead" folder

```
bash init.sh
```

then run the commands `vagrant up` and `vagrant provision` to that Vagrantfile, that should have been created inside `./Homestead`

Here is what the output of the `vagrant provision` command looks like on my system:

```
    vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-17xwlzk.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-rncs6l.sh
==> default: nginx stop/waiting
==> default: nginx start/running, process 1751
==> default: php5-fpm stop/waiting
==> default: php5-fpm start/running, process 1766
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-e9qxwn.sh
==> default: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
==> default: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-14rlz2c.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-16ethaq.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: php5-fpm stop/waiting
==> default: php5-fpm start/running, process 1861
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: You are already using composer version 92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/q6/pgygb1ln4rg7_nvv0p8n1v300000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150714-94163-btuuhg.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing net-tools on ubuntu fixed this for me

```
$ sudo install net-tools
$ vagrant destroy
$ vagrant up
```

Comment: why the downvote? if it didn't work for you, i don't see the need to downvote? It worked for others as well as myself.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this issue, and it turned out that nginx was failing to start due to an error when loading the TLS certificates. The `vagrant up` command doesn't report that nginx failed to start, or that any ports failed to bind.

To diagnose this, I did the following:

```
$ nmap homestead.app
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-03 16:16 NZDT
Nmap scan report for homestead.app (192.168.10.10)
Host is up (0.00077s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
1025/tcp open  NFS-or-IIS
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

There is no port 80 in the list. Let's double-check port 80.

```
$ nmap homestead.app -p 80
...
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http
```

So it is certainly closed. What do the guest logs say? `vagrant ssh` and...

```
    $ systemctl status nginx.service
    ...
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-10-03 03:06:12 UTC; 1min 30s ago
    ...
 homestead systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
 homestead nginx[1250]: nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICA
 homestead nginx[1250]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
 homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
homestead systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Nginx has failed to start due to an error in it's config. The `PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX` error points to the `/etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.crt` file. Where is that file used in the configuration?

```
$ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/homestead.app
```

I commented out the related lines:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 server {
     listen 80;
-    listen 443 ssl http2;
+#    listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name homestead.app;
     root "/home/vagrant/Code/public";

@@ -42,7 +42,7 @@ server {
         deny all;
     }

-    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.crt;
-    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.key;
+#    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.crt;
+#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.key;
 }
```

Start nginx with `$ sudo service start nginx` and run `nmap` again from the host.

```
$ nmap homestead.app -p 80,443
...
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
443/tcp closed https
```

Port 80 is open and should be accessible now from http://homestead.app . Of course TLS won't be working but you should be able to fix it by generating new certificates. I'm not sure of the reason for the certificates failing to load in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, but I made a change.

I changed my /etc/hosts file with this IP `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I’m trying to avoid using 127.0.0.1 so that I do not have to append the :8000 to every URL :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was solved by letting `vagrant up` install the guest additions:

```
~/Homestead (master|✔) $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
[...]
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.26) and guest (5.0.20) do not match.
[...]
Copy iso file /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.26 - guest version is 5.0.20
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.26 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.20 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used
```

After this point, I got a new interface with the expected IP address:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e8:04:04
          inet addr:192.168.8.10  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee8:404/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:996 (996.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue come up on my Windows machine and it turns out I had accidentally reversed the folders section "map" and "to". When I found that the folder wasn't underneath ~/code/ in the vagrant ssh session it was obvious it wasn't working right, but double checking the paths didn't yield anything.

Here is the correct way to map the folder section on your Windows machine:

```
folders:
    - map: D:/Development/PHP/projects/
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is need to put hostname and IP in host file

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

- Open Notepad as a Admin
- click open file and select "host" file
- put your domain (eg 192.168.10.10 homestead.app)
- save (make sure you are saving as Admin)

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Vagrant plugin

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
```

then run this in your homestead folder to provision again

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Then you do no need to update the host file every time you add a new project!